# How to map root of Web App in Stripes to an ActionBean

Tags: url, dictionary, root, stripes, urlbinding

I'm using DynamicMappingFilter and annotated URLs for all my actions.

I'm trying to map "/" to an existing actionBean.  The actionbean I want "/" to go to, is currently bound to "/categories".

I found two ways, but I'm wondering if there is a better way in terms of performance.

I created a new IndexActionBean with @UrlBinding("/") at the top.

Inside of it, I can return a ForwardResolution to the Categories class, or I can copy paste the category class code in it, since mine is very simple.

```
@UrlBinding("/")
public class IndexActionBean  extends AbstractActionBean {
  @DefaultHandler
  public ForwardResolution view() {
    return new ForwardResolution(ShowCategoryActionBean.class);
  }
}
```

It works, but I don't like having the overhead of the ForwardResolution, especially since this is the root page of the domain and will get a lot of pageviews.

I've tried to use the welcome file, but it doesn't work with DynamicMappingFilter.  It's working with DispatcherServlet, such as category.action, but even then, I had problems, and only / was working, and /category and all other urls stopped working and giving 404 not found.

```
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>category.action</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Any better ways?  I cannot just rename @UrlBinding of /categories to / because I still need /categories, but I want / to forward to it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IndexActionBean` extend `CategoriesBean` rather than `AbstractActionBean` that is:

```
@UrlBinding("/")
public class IndexActionBean  extends CategoriesBean {
}
```

So that you can have two url's mapped to same action bean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/index.jsp` to forward to your action.